# From figma to pixel perfect

Tags: html, css, frontend, figma, pixel-perfect

I have a figma design which I am to convert to a html and css template. There is only a dimension of 1440px for the design with. On which screen size should I start coding? Should I start on width 1440px and scale down/up to other screen size or start from mobile then scale up to other screen size?

What are the best practices to ensure responsiveness on different screen size?

Comment: Your story starts from Figma, but your question is not related to Figma.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to start with a larger screen size you need to take care of.

Here is a simple set of media-query CSS to get you started:

```
/* for 1200px or over */
.example {
}
/* 1199~992px */
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .example {
  }
}
/* 991~768px */
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .example {
  }
}
/* 767~480px */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .example {
  }
}
/* below 479px */
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .example {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start from the **mobile device** as it will be easier for you to implement the product
If you start on mobile, **you can easily implement elements and components on larger devices**